# DialogFragment Class Deprecated in Android P

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog, android-9.0-pie

The Android Documentation gives the following warning.

> This class was deprecated in API level P.
>   Use the Support Library DialogFragment for consistent behavior across all devices and access to Lifecycle.

Does this simply mean that the only change for me as a developer is to import `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment` instead of the old `android.app.DialogFragment`?

Comment: If you wish to avoid the deprecation warning, yes. They are pushing everyone to the Support Library edition of fragments across the board.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Google is encouraging all developers to shift from the ordinary DialogFragment to the support version of the same class, you can still use the deprecated version of course but if Google recommends the support version, why wouldn't you?

Simply change your import statement from `android.app.DialogFragment` to `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment`.

Also, consider changing all the imports if you are using the deprecated version of normal fragments.

**UPDATE**

If you are using the brand new AndroidX library instead of the old support library change it to `androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment` but pay attention about how you are using the DialogFragment in your code because you have to migrate also to the new `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity`.

Comment: Wow! thank you. you saved my day!!
the problem was I have to use FragmentActivity for my parent activity.

Comment: @MomenZaqout Glad I could help.

Comment: Thank you for this.

Answer (score 1):

Change your import statement from `android.app.DialogFragment` to `androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment`